# Laravel 5.8 Unable to find a file at path

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, file-upload

I know there have been a lot of similar issues, but I couldn't find solution for my problem.

I'm trying to make a test for PDF file upload, but I keep getting "**Unable to find a file at path [document.pdf].**" error. Everything seems to be just fine, according to the Laravel docs. What am I missing?

Controller is working fine, just as it should - it creates directory, stores a file and returns stream using PDFDOM library.

**My filesystem**

```
'disks' => [
    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
        'url' => storage_path('app')
    ],

    'pdf' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('pdf_reports'),
        'url' => storage_path('pdf_reports')
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
],
```

**My controller**

```
public function export_report(Request $request){    
    $path = 'internal/2020/APR/20/report.pdf';
    $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.report');
    $content = $pdf->download()->getOriginalContent();
    Storage::disk('pdf')->put($path , $content);
    return $pdf->stream(\Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('d_M_Y').'report.pdf');
}
```

**My TestCase**

```
public function pdf_uploaded()
{
    Storage::fake('pdf');

    $file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('document.pdf', -1024);

    $response = $this->json('POST', '/export/report', [
        'file' => $file,
    ]);

    // Assert the file was stored...
    Storage::disk('pdf')->assertExists($file->hashName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is from here `$file = UploadedFile::fake()->create('document.pdf', -1024);`

You need to specify the file path using e.g `public_path('document.pdf')` assuming the document.pdf file exists in public folder.